# How to use the ADD instruction with SIGNED integers in Assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, addition, x86-16

So if I wanted to add two unsigned ints I would simply write

```
dat1 db ff
dat2 db ff
res dw ?
```

and in the code segment:

```
mov ax, dat1
add ax, dat2
mov dl,0
adc dl,0 ;initialize the contents of dl and use it to store the carry flag
mov byte ptr res, ax
mov byte ptr res+1, dl
```

BUT, what would the code look like if I wanted to add two SIGNED integers? Can I somehow access the sign flag?

Comment: The addition is the same. That's the great thing about 2s complement math. It's just about how you interpret the numbers. I don't know about the sign flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the errors:

- It reads 16 bits from variables that allocate only 8 bits.
- It doesn't make sense to write to address res+1 either (but to res+2).
- also trying to write `mov byte ptr addr, ax` should fail

  - should be `mov word ptr res, ax`

Answer to the first question is: nothing special.
`add ax, bx` doesn't care if they are signed or not. The fun part comes when inspecting the status register. There you have the *carry flag*, *sign flag* and *overflow flag*. (and 25+ unrelated flags). As a side note: overflow flag is set, if carry_flag != sign_flag *for addends of the same sign*. It means that addition/subtraction of two negative numbers can be interpreted positive or adding two positive numbers can be *interpreted* as negative. For addends of different sign (3) + (-2) overflow doesn't happen.

Sign flag can be accessed by comparing and branching:

```
add ax,bx  
jns process_unsigned   // or
js process_signed
```

Or if you are concerned to transfer the sign bit of a register somewhere else, you can
 - `mov cl, 16; sar ax, cl;`  // shift the sign bit over the word ax  ***or***
 - `add ax, ax` (*or* `shl ax,1`)  // shift the sign bit out of the "left" side of AX to *Carry Bit*

Additionally one can `pushf` [status flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register), `pop ax` it to a general purpose register, and inspect any individual bits.

Comment: This is not true: `overflow flag is set, if carry_flag != sign_flag.` -2+1=-1 OF=0 CF=0 SF=1.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the bugs in the example code (see Aki's answer)...

If you're trying to add a pair of 24-bit numbers; then the first 24-bit number is positive because the sign bit for this number is in bit 7 of the 0 you move into DL (in the `mov dl,0` instruction). The second 24-bit number is also positive, because its sign bit is in bit 7 of the 0 you add to DL (in the `adc dl,0` instruction).

In this case, the result of the addition will be positive (adding 2 positive numbers will give a positive result), and the CPU's sign flag will correctly show that the result of adding the 24-bit numbers was positive. The CPU's carry flag and overflow flag will also be correct (and will both be clear); so you could test them normally using instructions like `js`, `jg` and `jo` (even though you know they're all clear and the conditional branches could be either removed or converted to `jmp`). The CPU's parity flag and zero flag may be wrong though (e.g. the zero flag will only say if the highest 8 bits are all zero and won't tell you if the entire 24-bits are all zero).

However, if you thought you were adding signed 16-bit numbers (and trying to get a 24-bit result), then you're doing it wrong and will get wrong results. To add signed 16-bit numbers and get a 24-bit result, you'd have to "sign extend" the 16-bit numbers to make them 24-bit and not "zero extend" those numbers. For example, the 16-bit (negative) number 0xCDEF should become the 24-bit (negative) number 0xFFCDEF and not the 24-bit (positive) number 0x00CDEF.

The other alternative would be to add 16-bit numbers like you normally would, then sign-extend the result to 24-bits. This only works if the 16-bit addition doesn't overflow, and if the addition can't overflow then you don't need a 24-bit result to begin with.

Comment: 24-bit number? Where would you get one of those?